# Can Autofixture create an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

Suppose I'd like a call in a unit test to return an anonymous type that looks like this -

```
var anonymousType = { id = 45, Name="MyName", Description="Whatever" }
```

Could Autofixture generate anonymousType?  If so, what's the syntax?

Comment: Consider to avoid anonymous types, since they are not too much transparent for other parts of system. You always create a DTO object instead or just use Dictionary<..., ...>. Whenever you wish to use anonymous type think twice and then consider to use DTO ;) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, AutoFixture doesn't support anonymous types, as they're internal to the library that uses them.

Answer (score 2):

As @MarkSeemann [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36555073/26396), AutoFixture *cannot* support anonymous types.

### Notes on AutoFixture and *dynamic*

This may not apply to your specific case, but I think it's worth mentioning that if you need to create instances of *dynamically typed objects* in your tests – and you aren't concerned about their particular state – you *can* configure AutoFixture to create instances of [`DynamicObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx) that respond to *any* property or method that you invoke on them.

Here's an example:

```
public class DynamicCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Insert(
            0,
            new FilteringSpecimenBuilder(
                new FixedBuilder(new AnythingObject()),
                new ExactTypeSpecification(typeof(object))));
    }

    private class AnythingObject : DynamicObject
    {
        public override bool TryGetMember(
            GetMemberBinder binder,
            out object result)
        {
            result = new AnythingObject();
            return true;
        }

        public override bool TryInvokeMember(
            InvokeMemberBinder binder,
            object[] args,
            out object result)
        {
            result = new AnythingObject();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the `AnythingObject` simply returns a new instance of itself for any  property or method it receives a call for. This would allow you to say for example:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize(new DynamicCustomization());

var foo = fixture.Create<dynamic>();

Assert.NotNull(foo.Bar);
Assert.NotNull(foo.Baz());
```

Another alternative – albeit more fragile – could be to use AutoFixture to create values for *specific properties*. In that case you would have to pass the `Fixture` object to `AnythingObject` like in this example:

```
public class DynamicCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Insert(
            0,
            new FilteringSpecimenBuilder(
                new FixedBuilder(new AnythingObject(fixture)),
                new ExactTypeSpecification(typeof(object))));
    }

    private class AnythingObject : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly SpecimenContext context;

        public AnythingObject(ISpecimenBuilder builder)
        {
            context = new SpecimenContext(builder);
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(
            GetMemberBinder binder,
            out object result)
        {
            if (binder.Name == "Bar")
            {
                result = context.Resolve(typeof(string));
            }
            else
            {
                result = new AnythingObject(context.Builder);
            }

            return true;
        }

        public override bool TryInvokeMember(
            InvokeMemberBinder binder,
            object[] args,
            out object result)
        {
            result = new AnythingObject(context.Builder);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here we're looking for a property named `"Bar"` and provide a `string` for it, while everything else will just get an instance of `AnythingObject`. So we can say:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize(new DynamicCustomization());

var foo = fixture.Create<dynamic>();

Assert.IsType<string>(foo.Bar);
Assert.NotNull(foo.Baz);
```

Comment: While Mark's answer is THE answer, this is interesting and I'll certainly play with it.  Thank you very much.